# In Scala, is there a way to "pass through" traits to variables within a class?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a trait NYSE that can retrieve the market currency

```
trait NYSE extends Market {
  override def getCurrency = "USD"
}
```

Now suppose I have a Trader class that needs to know the currency. Easy:

```
val trader = new Trader with NYSE
```

However suppose within Trader I have something like

```
val Database = new Database
```

But I really want to pass market information so that

```
val trader = new Trader with NYSE
```

Automatically initialises the internal variable as follows

```
val Database = new Database with NYSE
```

Similarly

```
val trader = new Trader with LSE
```

Automatically does

```
val Database = new Database with LSE
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think type classes are perfect for what you are looking for:

```
trait Currency[T] { def get: String }
trait DatabaseProvider[T] { def get: String }

object Markets {

  trait NYSE

  implicit case object NYSECurrency extends Currency[NYSE] {
    def get = "USD"
  }
  implicit case object NYSEDBProvider extends DatabaseProvider[NYSE] {
    def get = "NYSE_DB"
  }

}

class Trader[T]( 
  implicit val currency: Currency[T],
  val dbProvider: DatabaseProvider[T]
) {
  def getCurrency = currency.get
  def getDatabase = dbProvider.get
}

object Demo extends App {
  import Markets._
  val trader = new Trader[NYSE]
  println( trader.getCurrency )
  println( trader.getDatabase )
}
```

You can add as many markets you want and you uncouple completely the different implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just

```
trait DatabaseProvider { def getDatabase: Database }

class Trader extends DatabaseProvider {
  val Database = getDatabase
  ...
}

trait NYSE extends Market with DatabaseProvider {
  override def getCurrency = "USD"
  def getDatabase = new Database with NYSE
}
```

Comment: Suppose in Database I wish to do: def myFunction { val currency = getCurrency }.  Can this be done?

Comment: @deltanovember - Not as far as I know, not as written.